# traefik v2 can't curl from inside via domain to other container of my docker

Tags: docker, networking, routes, traefik

I try to accomplish the following thing:
From **Service B** I want to call **Service A**

**Working:**

- From external (not on the server) connect to Service A via: sub.example.org/route
- From Service B connect via: servicename:port/route

**Not working (No feedback from curl, no error):**

- From Service B calling the same url like when calling from outside: sub.example.org/route

So I did try to debug this, but curl and traefik dont show logs, where the catch is. CURL is just hanging.

> nslookup of sub.example.org  => ok
>   ping of sub.example.org  => ok
>   curl of sub.example.org => hangs not output beside: connecting to ip

---

All external domains/routes are SSL encrpyted

---

[image]

Comment: "Not working" is not a very good problem description

Comment: I didn't get a response from curl. So no feedback, no error.

Comment: enable debug logging

Comment: In Traefik Log their are no entrys when curling the domain or any route.

Comment: on curl - that's where you are not getting info you want

Comment: What is the output of `telnet sub.example.org 443` from inside the container B (install telnet there if it doesn't exit)?

Comment: did you solved this problem? I'm facing the same right now